# suddenly throwing This RDD lacks a SparkContext it was working before every code was in main method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

It was a working piece of code but suddenly its not working after I tried creating `Sparksession` from different `scala object`

```
val b = a.filter { x => (!x._2._1.isEmpty) && (!x._2._2.isEmpty) } 

val primary_ke = b.map(rec => (rec._1.split(",")(0))).distinct 

for (i <- primary_key_distinct) {    
  b.foreach(println)

}
```

Error:

```
 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 5)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext. It could happen in the following cases: 
(1) RDD transformations and actions are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
(2) When a Spark Streaming job recovers from checkpoint, this exception will be hit if a reference to an RDD not defined by the streaming job is used in DStream operations. For more information, See SPARK-13758.
```

Not working even after I revoked it and I'm not using any objects.

Code Updated:

```
object try {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {



val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("50columns3nodes").getOrCreate()

var s = spark.read.csv("/home/hadoopuser/Desktop/input/source.csv").rdd.map(_.mkString(","))
var k = spark.read.csv("/home/hadoopuser/Desktop/input/destination.csv").rdd.map(_.mkString(","))

val source_primary_key = s.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0), rec))
val destination_primary_key = k.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0), rec))

val a = source_primary_key.cogroup(destination_primary_key).filter { x => ((x._2._1) != (x._2._2)) }
val b = a.filter { x => (!x._2._1.isEmpty) && (!x._2._2.isEmpty) } 

var extra_In_Dest = a.filter(x => x._2._1.isEmpty && !x._2._2.isEmpty).map(rec => (rec._2._2.mkString(""))) 
var extra_In_Src = a.filter(x => !x._2._1.isEmpty && x._2._2.isEmpty).map(rec => (rec._2._1.mkString(""))) 

val primary_key_distinct = b.map(rec => (rec._1.split(",")(0))).distinct 
for (i <- primary_key_distinct) {

  var lengthofarray = 0
  println(i)
  b.foreach(println)

}
}
}
```

Input data follows

`s=1,david
2,ajay
3,jijo
4,abi
5,surendhar`

`k=1,david
2,ajay
3,jijoaa
4,abisdsdd
5,surendhar`

val a contains {3,(jijo,jijoaa),5(abi,abisdsdd)}

Comment: Is variable `a` RDD?

Comment: Did you read the complete error message?

Comment: sparkContext needs to be created in driver class and not anywhere else. I guess you created sparkContext in another class rather than the driver class. Thats what the error message is suggesting.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, yes before I tried to write `SparkContext` in different scala method it throw some error so I revoked it but still its throwing the same error even after I clean my project for several times like `sbt clean, eclipse project clean`. Is there any other way I can do it to resolve.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala `val a: RDD[(String, (Iterable[String], Iterable[String]))]` a is RDD of cogroup

Comment: I guess you must have missed to remove it somewhere else. Its very difficult to tell until we all of your code and your project.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, Code Updated

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, Sorry All for the late reply Network here is very unreliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read carefully the first message

> (1) RDD transformations and actions are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

**It clearly states that *actions* and *transformations* cannot be performed inside a *transformation*.**

`primary_key_distinct` is *transformation* done on `b` and `b` itself is a *transformation* done on `a`. And `b.foreach(println)` is an *action* done inside *transformation* of `primary_key_distinct`

So if you collect `b` or `primary_key_distinct` inside driver, then the code should run properly

```
val b = a.filter { x => (!x._2._1.isEmpty) && (!x._2._2.isEmpty) }.collect
```

**or**

```
val primary_key_distinct = b.map(rec => (rec._1.split(",")(0))).distinct.collect
```

**or** if you don't use *action* inside another *transformation* then the code should run properly too as

```
for (i <- 1 to 2) {

  var lengthofarray = 0
  println(i)
  b.foreach(println)

}
```

I hope the explanation is clear.