# How to solve SPARK-5063 issue "this RDD lacks a SparkContext"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using Scala 2.12.7 and Spark 2.4.3, I have an algorithm to compute kNN using an `RDD[(List[Double], String)]`

```
def classifyPoint(point: List[Double], data: RDD[(List[Double], String)], k: Int): String =
  {
    val sortedDistances = data.map{case (a, b) => (b, Util.euclideanDistance(point, a))}.sortBy(_._2, ascending = true)

    val topk = sortedDistances.zipWithIndex().filter(_._2 < k)

    val result = topk.map(_._1).map(entry => (entry._1, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_).sortBy(_._2, ascending = false).first()._1

    //for debugging purposes, remember to remove
    println(s"Point classified as ${result}")

    result
  }
```

With an `RDD[List[Double]]` called `testVector`, I'd like to compute in parallel the classification process using this line (the function classifyPoint previously described is in a class),:

```
val classificationKnn = testVector.map(knnSpark.classifyPoint(_, modelKnn, k))
```

where `modelKnn` is a `RDD[(List[Double], String)]`

However this approach gives me an error "this RDD lacks a SparkContext", which as far as I understand is linked to nested RDD operations.

Is there a way to avoid this issue and still be able to have parallel computation?

If I transform `testVector` in a list with `testVector.collect().toList`, I no longer have the same problem, but this also means giving up the possibility of classifying each point in parallel.

Comment: probably because you are performing action `.first()._1` inside transformation `testVector.map`, check it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48113692/9687910

Comment: by removing what you've mentioned, I still get "MapPartitionsRDD: Spark does not support nested RDDs (see SPARK-5063)"